Why I am not able navigate to HomeScreen after displaying Text for 2 seconds in React Native?
So, I am trying display HomeScreen after displaying a Text "Hello App" initially when I open the App. It should display the Text "Hello App" for 2 seconds and then display HomeScreen. Below is the code
App.js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Image, View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import * as SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen';

const SplashScreenComponent = ({navigation}) => {
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
const hideSplash = async () => {
  await SplashScreen.hide(); // Hide the splash screen after 2 seconds
  setIsVisible(false);
  navigation.navigate(HomeScreen);
};

const timeoutId = setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000); // Delay for 2 seconds

return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId); // Clear timeout on component unmount 
}, [navigation]);

return (
isVisible && (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Hello App</Text>
  </View>
));};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'white', // Optional background color
},
image: {
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
resizeMode: 'cover', // Adjust resize mode as needed
},});
export default SplashScreenComponent;
This is the code of my HomeScreen.js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>Welcome to Home Screen!</Text>
</View> 
);};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
},});

export default HomeScreen;`

I have created a HomeScreen and imported it in App.js and put it as an argument in navigation.navigate(HomeScreen). This is the errorenter image description here that I am displaying

It should be navigation.navigate('HomeScreen') you have written navigation.navigate(HomeScreen);

@Pixel When I do , the import HomeScreen line in App.js gives following message 'HomeScreen' is defined but never used
